# Rest Webservice Moodle: Reset a test attempt for a quiz for a user

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I want to reset a test result for a user over the rest API from Moodle 4.1 and  don't find a solution. Is there a way to do this?
I have the user id from the user from moodle and the course id and quiz id. Now I want to delete or reset the test of this user without login over the rest API.

I found the `mod_quiz_start_attempt` function that looks like what I want to do, but there I can't say for which user I want a new attempt for the test. When I tested it, it always create a new attempt for the user of the Rest API.

Example:

`/webservice/rest/server.php?wsfunction=mod_quiz_start_attempt&forcenew=1&wstoken=<token>&quizid=<courseId>&moodlewsrestformat=json`

Is there a way to add an user here or is there any other possibility to solve this problem?